# how to convert base64 to a zipped file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this format and i wanted to convert this into a zipped file and unzipped that file using javascript. when i am converting this https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file?fbclid=IwAR3X1qwrnSLTw9cHT9iKl5HxiCRmKG5l0tForN3Odraz_4pYsYApoVprEJE it will give a zipped file and i have to unzip the file to excess the data

```
{
    "awslogs": {
        "data": "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"
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not give a zipped file. The first couple of bytes are `3a8ccc29` which isn't a file signature for anything that I know of.

Comment: i have updated the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use node's [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) and [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) modules in order to parse as base64 and gunzip:

```js
const zlib = require("zlib");
function unzip(str) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        // we read in the base64
        const data = Buffer.from(str, "base64");
        // we create a transform string to gunzip it
        const gzip = zlib.createGunzip();
        // initialize ret with an empty buffer
        let ret = Buffer.alloc(0);
        gzip.on("data", function(dat) {
            // concatenate the data to ret
            ret = Buffer.concat([ret, dat], res.length + dat.length);
        });
        gzip.on("error", function(err) {
            rej(err);
        });
        gzip.on("end", function() {
            // we're done, resolve the promise
            res(ret);
        });
        // send the data to the gunzip stream
        gzip.end(data);
    });
}

const data = "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";
// this uses promises for asynchronous execution
unzip(data).then(v => console.log(v.toString("utf8")));
```

Comment: zlib and buffer are built in to node so it's about as far as away from a library as possible.

Comment: actually i have to run this code in aws lambda so I am new to the aws lambda I don't know how to import library in that's why I asked you

Comment: They're build in to node: you don't have to have any additional libraries.

Comment: but i have to install zlib using npm and have to require to run locally

Comment: No you don't, zlib is built into node. Yes, you have to require it. No, you do not have to download it.

Comment: can you please tell me console.log(v.toString("utf8")) returns a typeof string and i wanted an object is it possible to convert this into an object?

Comment: You can use `JSON.parse(v.toString("utf8"))`.

Comment: I have used that but still the type  is a string and i have to add this in cloud firestore which accepts objects

Comment: In your example, you had a terminating null byte, so you might have to get rid of it with `JSON.parse(v.toString("utf8").replace(/\0/g, ""))`.